# Adding Code Snippet to Resources - Gradle / Twitter API

Tags: java, gradle, twitter

I am using the Twitter API to learn about how APIs work, and I ran into a spot that confused me. The docs tell you to add a code snippet to your resources for the app. Do I add a file? If so, what type?

[image: Code Snippet]

The code snippet above is supposed to go in my resources. What file should I add to do so?

[image: My project Structure]

I looked for solutions to this, but they troubleshoot very specific issues. I am looking for a general explanation of how to add resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is "application.properties" and does need to be added to the resources folder.